# Html form, relative target

Tags: html, get, request

Let's assume my website is deployed at localhost/MySite

And I have a form with the target:

"MyController"

Then on click, a request will be sent to localhost/MyController

Instead of to

localhost/MySite/MyController.

I can't guess what the site's name will be called,

Is there any elegant way to send a relative request instead?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like:

```
<form action="../../MyController" method="get">
```

You can always make the form action a php variable, and update the definition once you know where the controller will be.

To read the current page url, add this to the page:

```
<?php 
function CurrentPageURL() 
{
$pageURL = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$pageURL .= $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '80' ? $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

Then echo the curPageURL in the form action:

```
<form action="<?php echo CurrentPageURL();?>/MyController">
```

Comment: That would still send a request to localhost/MyController won't it? What I want is to append the 'MyController' to the end of the current url

Comment: you can read the current page url by adding this:  <?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?> then reading it with this:  <?php
  echo curPageURL();
?>